# Why does my Unit Test work from Visual Studio 2010 and not with Jenkins?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, jenkins, mstest

I have a **unit test that works with Microsoft Excel**, using the interop assembly from Microsoft. When executing the unit test from within **Visual Studio, then everything is fine** and the test passes. When I run the same test on the same machine **using Jenkins, the test fails.**

**About the test:** Basically it just creates a new Excel datasheet, manipulates it a bit and then saves it to an excel file. I know that there are many troubles with interop and excel, but since the test works in Visual Studio, this is more about differences to Jenkins. The test is called as "Windows Batch command" with the following code:

```
echo Executing Unit Tests...
del /f/q results.trx 
call "%MSTEST%\mstest.exe" /testcontainer:"%WORKSPACE%\xxx.Test\bin\Debug\xxx.Test.dll" /testsettings:Local.Testsettings /resultsfile:results.trx
```

The offending line is the following, which saves the excel workbook to a file (which does not exist yet):

```
excelWorkbook.SaveAs(destFilePath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

The exception received is:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

**About the Jenkins installation:** The machine (with Windows 7) on which I have installed Jenkins also has a full installation of Visual Studio on it, used for the comparison, and Microsoft Office Excel of course. I expected the troubles coming from the fact that, when started with Jenkins, the test can not properly interact with the desktop, [as required by Excel according to Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).
I have configured the Jenkins service the following ways, for testing.

- The standard way, as service
- As service, with Desktop interaction allowed
- As admin user (the same as I logged on when using Visual Studio)

None of these 3 variants worked. 
EDIT: By malenkiy_scot, I learned that starting it explicitly as logged on user, it works. Thus the question is now: **What is the difference of any of the above variants with this way?**

**Has anyone brought this to work? What is the difference between Visual Studio and Jenkins when executing this test?**

Thanks for hints!

Comment: What happens when you run Jenkins 'explicitly', not as a service?

Comment: @malenkiy_scot, Good point, I'll try that!

Comment: @malenkiy_scot, It worked. However, it feels somewhat disturbing to run jenkins under a normal user account. I fear, that this will bite me sometime one way or the other.

Comment: I had similar problems with PhotoShop tests a year or so ago. I ended up creating a Jenkins slave that ran in the foreground as a 'normal' user specifically for those tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've noted in the comment, you can create a slave instance (even on the same machine) that would run as a regular user in the foreground. Tie the jobs that would not run in the service instance to that slave.

Comment: I'll accept that because it would surely help. The solution I currently use is however, that I run the whole Jenkins under an interactive logon user. Feels bad, but works.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that the user account Jenkins is running under is able to interact with the desktop.

Ie, run services.msc, select your Jenkins service, bring up properties, switch to 'Log On' tab and verify that the 'Allow service to interact with desktop' box is checked.

Generally you'll want to do this if there's any kind of a dialog that pops up when something in your test runs (even if it doesn't require input of any kind).

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the hint, but I have already tried this. (And stated so in the question)